# Is there a Stack Exchange site for startups / business advice?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site for startups / business advice?

Comment: For future reference, you can search [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Stack Exchange site for startups is http://answers.onstartups.com.

Comment: Correction.  Apparently the stack exchange site for startups *was* that link.  It's gone.

Comment: Today, March/2015, there is http://startups.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As this is the accepted answer - can you update it (see the other answer)?

Comment: Nope, that one is gone now too :(

Answer (score 5):

There used to be a beta site on https://startups.stackexchange.com, but it was closed 2017/2018 due to insufficient activity, as described on https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62811/ (the former site now redirects to the latter).

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that due to the failure of both of the two past betas for sites about startups, the SE team is now rejecting any new attempt to start such a site on Area 51.