# Confused to ask business advice consulting via a Stack Exchange site

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I need to clarify some aspects of my business, so I want to ask about some business models via Stack Exchange. I found these [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78142/is-there-a-stack-exchange-site-for-startups-business-advice) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169515/what-is-the-best-stack-exchange-site-where-business-related-questions-can-be-ask) with suggested asking via:

http://workplace.stackexchange.com

And

https://startups.stackexchange.com

So **startups.stackexchange.com** has been closed, and I asked by:

[money.stack exchange](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/115166/searching-international-funds-for-extending-business)

and

[workplace.stackexchange.com](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/145581/searching-international-funds-for-extending-business?noredirect=1#comment469097_145581)

Which both of them had been on hold. So where can I ask this kind of question? Could I ask on the main Stack Overflow site?

**UPDATE:**

For Example the question is :

[Searching international funds for extending business](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/145581/searching-international-funds-for-extending-business)

Shown Below:

[image]

The comments were:

> deleted by Mister Positive♦ yesterday
>
> put on hold as off-topic by Justin Cave, DarkCygnus, Dan Neely,
>   espindolaa, gnat yesterday
>
> This question appears to be off-topic for this site. While what’s on-
>   and off-topic is not always intuitive, you can learn more about it by
>   reading the help center. The users who voted to close gave this
>   specific reason:
>
> ```
> "Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies should be directed to your manager or HR
> ```
>
> department. Questions that address only a specific company or position
>   are of limited use to future visitors. Questions seeking legal advice
>   should be directed to legal professionals. For more information, click
>   here." – Justin Cave, DarkCygnus, espindolaa
>
> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center,
>   please edit your question.
>
> ```
> 2
> ```
>
> This is borderline SPAM in my opinion, voting to close. Besides it's
>   asking on how to get funds not how to navigate the Workplace. –
>   DarkCygnus yesterday 2 I don't expect this is on topic here any more
>   than it was on the personal finance site
>   money.stackexchange.com/questions/115166/… – Justin Cave yesterday
>   @JustinCave cross-posting is highly discouraged on SE... – DarkCygnus
>   yesterday @DarkCygnus - Agreed. Did you intend that for the original
>   poster? I was just pointing out the cross-post. – Justin Cave
>   yesterday Based of tour (Real problems or questions that you’ve
>   encountered pertaining to a workplace) and [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78142/is-there-a-stack-exchange-site-for-startups-business-advice) i prefer
>   to ask here. [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78142/is-there-a-stack-exchange-site-for-startups-business-advice): meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169515/… –
>   moha_alpha-web.net yesterday   @JustinCave it was intended for OP
>   mostly. For OP to be aware of it, and also as a hat-tip to the cross
>   post you found – DarkCygnus yesterday 1 This question isn't about the
>   workplace. Its about business. Maybe you should look hiring a
>   consultant or Lawyer to guide you on through the steps you need to
>   take. Advise from a single session is one thing. Having them work with
>   you is another matter. – Shadowzee yesterday

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of question you want to ask?

Comment: Well, people ask about the CAN bus protocol on Stack Overflow, so why not?

Comment: I have added the question exmple and Updated the question.

Comment: @moha_alpha-web.net: The example question page you linked to is inaccessible (404 -- or maybe it's a deleted question that requires lots of rep on WorkPlace). Can you add a quote with the key points of the question.

Comment: FYI, due to US OFAC regulation, if you register as being domiciled in another country, and are caught, not only is your business at risk, so is everyone else who does business with you. Especially any bank who opens an account for you or lends you money. You’ll have your assets frozen and the bank will be in big trouble. Why does the US matter? Because its financial system is global enough and attractive enough that most other developed geographies (EU and NZ included) apply OFAC regulation.

Answer (score 3):

Context: I was the highest rep user on Startups, and a lower rep participant in its prior iteration -- which also got shut down.

In my view both sites got shut down for basically the same reason. On both sites there were a handful of regulars who gave some time to the site to the best of their ability, but they were basically busy. On both sites, you had a bunch of students or inexperienced first time business creators who asked a bunch of questions as they went through their thing and eventually either had all their questions answered (or not) or became too busy to contribute answers.

This led to a triple problem:

Experienced answerers were few and could only answer so many questions from newcomers.

New entrepreneurs didn't always get good answers. I don't mean to disparage age groups, but on Startups it was fairly common to read youngsters out of college try to give advice to the occasional more experienced would-be entrepreneurs. The latter showed up with rather specific questions on a topic they're less familiar with. More often than not the answers they got were hilariously bad -- as in so bad that anyone with a few years of experience in the workplace would just know they were just terrible.

The net result of this is that only a tiny handful of very committed users stayed along, and the place ended up swamped by young adults asking questions and receiving no answers, or young adults talking to one another. The questions were rather low quality. The answers were very low quality.

Just about no one ended up monitoring what was going on in the end and spammy or very low quality questions and answers slowly crept in. The first site was shut down because it didn't meet graduation criteria on time -- in part, I would presume, because it was turning into a sewers. The second site was shut down *because* it turned into a sewers.

But who knows, maybe it was just poorly scoped. FYI there was a marketing proposal or something to that effect in Area 51 at some point if I remember correctly. If it is still around you might want to cast your vote on it to make it happen.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that as of 2019, there is nowhere on Stack Exchange network of sites where you could ask this question. It’s not on topic for any Stack Exchange  site.